# Premiere Pro importing DV file -- no audio

Tags: video, dvd, dv, adobe-premiere

I'm new to Adobe Premiere Pro (CS5.5) and trying to import an old family DVD to do some editing.

I've used MPEG Streamclip to rip the DVD to DV, however when I import it to Premiere, I don't get any audio.

I've checked all the obvious things, and can confirm that generating bars & tone does make a sound, so it would appear that there is some sort of codec issue with Premiere and this particular file. (The DV file plays fine with audio in VLC).

VLC reports that from the file, Stream 1:

- Type: Audio
- Codec: PCM S16 LE (s16I)
- Channels: Stereo
- Sample rate: 48000 Hz
- Bits per sample: 16

Meanwhile, Premiere Pro reports:

- File Path: C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\VTS_01_1.dv
- Type: QuickTime Movie
- File Size: 21.5 GB
- Image Size: 720 x 576
- Frame Rate: 25.00
- Source Audio Format: 48000 Hz - 16 bit - Stereo
- Project Audio Format: 48000 Hz - 32-bit floating point - Stereo
- Total Duration: 01:46:45:17
- Average Data Rate: 3.4 MB / second
- Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1.0940

It makes no sense to me that Premiere wouldn't be able to play PCM audio -- what do you think I might be missing here?

Comment: Might want to check out the Adobe Forums. Might get a quicker or better answer there. http://forums.adobe.com/community/premiere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been several hours and not got a response, but in case anyone out there has the same issue with MPEG Streamclip, I just opted to export as AVI but set the codec to DV and left audio uncompressed.

Resulting file is a little bigger than a straight DV file, but at least it now works in Premiere Pro!

(You could probably opt to compress the audio but (a) I didn't notice a huge difference in resulting bitrate whether compression was used or not, and (b) lossy compression will mean you are throwing away some data, which I didn't want to do in this case!)